# Powershell looping through files to pass to a program as a parameter

Tags: powershell

I have the following two cmd.exe commands, but I need to convert them to Powershell, and I've failed miserably trying to figure it out. Line 1 is finding a dll, but only when in a bin folder and line two then takes all the entries it finds and runs a command with it, e.g. bin\Debug\file, bin\Release\file

Can anyone help? The only limitation is this is inside a yaml runner file so I don't think I can split lines for each part, e.g. I don't think a Foreach-Object will work.

```
dir /s /b RunnerUnitTest.dll | findstr /r bin\\ > tests_list.txt
for /f %f in (tests_list.txt) do vstest.console.exe "%f"
```

I got as far as this

```
(gci -r RunnerUnitTest.dll).FullName | select-string bin
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A single command (pipeline), spread across 3 lines for readability, using built-in *command aliases* for brevity (but the *parameter names* are spelled out, for long-term robustness):

```
gci -Recurse -Filter RunnerUnitTest.dll | 
  ? FullName -match bin\\ | 
    % { vstest.console.exe $_.FullName }
```

- `gci -Recurse -Filter RunnerUnitTest.dll` finds all `RunnerUnitTest.dll` in the current directory's subtree; `-Filter` makes for faster matching than using the (positionally implied) `-Path` parameter.
- `? FullName -match bin\\` uses `?` (`Where-Object`) to test the `.FullName` (full path) property values of the input file-info objects for matching regex `bin\\`, i.e. for a literal `bin\` substring, and only passes matching file-info objects on.
- `% { vstest.console.exe $_.FullName }` uses `%` (`ForEach-Object`) to invoke `vstest.console.exe` with each matching file's full path.

Note that no intermediate file with a list of DLLs to process is created, because it isn't necessary.

---

If you need to pass the above to an explicit invocation of the PowerShell CLI, you'd do:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "gci -Recurse -Filter RunnerUnitTest.dll | ? FullName -match bin\\ | % { vstest.console.exe $_.FullName }"
```

<sup>If you're using PowerShell [Core] 6+, substitute `pwsh` for `powershell`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Write a multi-line powershell script to do the work and then call that script from your yaml runner.

```
powershell -file "c:\myscripts\runtests.ps1" "c:\mydlls\RunnerUnitTest.dll" "c:\mytests\tests_list.txt"
```